# using polygon batch overlay of lecos error

Tags: qgis, error

I´m trying to analyse corine land cover with polygon batch overlay of lecos and do get this error:

```
Ein Fehler trat bei der Ausführung von Python-Code auf: 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetFeatureCount' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/deniseehrhardt/.qgis2/python/plugins/LecoS/lecos_dlg.py", line 876, in accept
    self.Output(results)
  File "/Users/deniseehrhardt/.qgis2/python/plugins/LecoS/lecos_dlg.py", line 951, in Output
    attr = func.getAttributeList(self.vector,self.LandID)
  File "/Users/deniseehrhardt/.qgis2/python/plugins/LecoS/lecos_functions.py", line 248, in getAttributeList
    for i in range(0,d.GetFeatureCount()):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetFeatureCount'


Python-Version: 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] 
QGIS-Version: 2.18.9 Las Palmas, exported
```

Here´s a screenshot... after pressing ok the error occurs...
[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have the scipy, numpy and pil installed?

Comment: yes, I do have all of them installed...